# terminology question: finding "strength" of variable on outcome

Tags: generalized-linear-model, terminology, importance

I'm doing this, and it works.  I know it has to have a name.

(background) I'm using a linear model (glm) and I get parameter estimates of various magnitude.  My general formula is $ y = \alpha_1 \cdot x_1 ... + \alpha_n \cdot x_n + \epsilon $.  Y is a binomial valued, and I am using logit-link.

(what I do) When I want to find parameters that, all else being equal, more strongly impact the variable of interest after fitting, I look at mean values of the measure, and multiply it by the parameter estimate.  That is to say, the fit gives me the $\alpha_i$ values then I find the product $\alpha_i \cdot E\left(x_i\right)$ and use them to compare strength of $x_i$ on $y$.

What is the proper term for what I am doing?

I am tempted to use words like "importance", "leverage", "significance" or "impact" but those all have very narrowly defined meanings that might not necessarily apply here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to assess and compare the [economic significance](http://marcfbellemare.com/wordpress/11680) of the variable. I've seen more often the standard deviation used instead of the means.

The reason why the expectation might not be a good choice for what you're doing is this. Consider the expected value of the dependent variable:
$$ E[y] = \alpha_1 E[ x_1] ... + \alpha_n E[ x_n]$$
As you can see your measure of strength can be interpreted as the contribution of the variable to the **mean** of the dependent variable.

This could be exactly what you're looking for in your particular situation, however, let's just change one of the variable, maybe introduce an offset: $\tilde x_1=x_1-C$, now we get:
$$ E[y] = \alpha_1 E[ \tilde x_1] + \alpha_1 C ... + \alpha_n E[ x_n]$$
All of a sudden the contribution (strength) changed by simply changing the variable's starting point. Is this desirable? Again, it may be in your case, but in most cases it would not be a desired feature.

Also, often we're not very interested in the mean of dependent variable, but we're interested in its response to an input. If variable $x_1$ typically varies a lot, then $\alpha \sigma_{x_1}$ would indicate how much this variable contributes into the variation if $y$. Of course, this would ignore the covariances, so it's not a perfect measure either.

There is not standard way of measuring the strength of the variable or its economic significance. It depends on the application.